# How to Upload Gallery Image on parse.com in Android?

Tags: android, parse-platform, image-gallery

I have created an Android application in which stores the user name, phone, passcode, latitude, and longitude on parse.com. all these values stored on parse.com successfully when I click on the submit button. Here is the code

LoginSigupActivity.java

```java
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    usernametxt = username.getText().toString();
                    passcodetxt = passcode.getText().toString();
                    phonetxt = phone.getText().toString();

                    if (usernametxt.equals("") && passcodetxt.equals("")) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Please complete the signup form",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    } else {
                        // Save new user data into Parse.com Data Storage
                        ParseUser user = new ParseUser();
                        user.setUsername(usernametxt);
                        user.setPassword(passcodetxt);
                        user.put("phone", phone.getText().toString());
                        user.put("passcode", passcode.getText().toString());
                        //user.put("profile_pic", "my profile pic");

                        // code to send the current latlong using parse.com
                        user.put("latitude", gpsTracker.getLatitude() + "");
                        user.put("longitude", gpsTracker.getLongitude() + "");
                        
                        
                        user.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
                            public void done(ParseException e) {
                                if (e == null) {

                                    Intent intent = new Intent(
                                            LoginSignupActivity.this, Welcome.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);

                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                            "Successfully Signed up !!!",
                                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                            "Sign up Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                            .show();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }

                }

            });

        }
    }
```

Now when the second activity is open here I used image view, get image button and upload image button.on click of get image button image get properly in image view but when I try to upload then its not upload.

Here is the code:

Welcome.java

```java
    selectImageButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.selectImageButton);
            // initlize gps tracker
            gpsTracker = new GPSTracker(this);

            String picturePath = PreferenceManager
                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getString("picturePath", "");
            if (!picturePath.equals("")) {
                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.uploadImage);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
            }

            selectImageButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.selectImageButton);
            selectImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(
                            Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
                }
            });
                    

           uploadButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.uploadButton);

            uploadButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @SuppressWarnings("null")
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {  
                    
                    ParseUser user = new ParseUser();
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);
                    // Convert it to byte
                    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    // Compress image to lower quality scale 1 - 100
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                    byte[] image = stream.toByteArray();

                    // Create the ParseFile
                    ParseFile file = new ParseFile("androidbegin.png", image);
                    // Upload the image into Parse Cloud
                    file.saveInBackground();

            
                    });*/

                    user.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
                        public void done(ParseException e) {
                            if (e == null) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                        "Successfully Signed up !!!",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                        "Sign up Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });

                }
            });

            // Retrieve current user from Parse.com
            ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
           // Convert currentUser into String
            String struser = currentUser.getUsername().toString();
           // Locate Button in welcome.xml
            logout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.logout);
            // Logout Button Click Listener
            logout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Welcome.this,
                            LoginSignupActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }      
      
       

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();

                // GET IMAGE PATH
                imagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);

                // IMAGE NAME
                imageName = imagePath.substring(imagePath.lastIndexOf("/"));

                // Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);
                //
                // // DISPLAY IMAGE
                // imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                // imageLocationTextView.setText("File path :" + imagePath);
            }
        }

        private String getPath(Uri uri) {
            String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
            int column_index = cursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        }
    }
```

Now I want to know how to upload the selected image from the gallery on parse.com, as my other parameter is saved on parse. I am also confused because I upload the user name, pass code, lat, long and phone from my First activity. But I get image from gallery in second activity.

Now I want to know how to upload selected image in the same class in parse.com (where the first activity parameter is saved). User is the my class name in parse.com.

Comment: Where are you storing the file in parse.com?

Comment: I have stored the file under the profile_pic column in User class.

Comment: Where in your code, your telling to parse.com to store the parsefile object in profile_pic?

Comment: in first activity under the else condition like this              user.put("profile_pic", "my profile pic");

Comment: ur getting ur code right? you're storing string in that line, then how ru expecting image to be store?

Comment: please tell me the step by step...i am new in parse.com...i have no idea...

Comment: I have add the string in that line...because i want to store the image with other parameter in the same class of parse.com...i have used only one class in parse.com...if i create new parse object in the second class nd try to upload the image then it create new parse class..that i dont want...i want to store data under only one(user) class..

Comment: ok thanx...is that code is used on uploadbutton click....

Comment: @HarshaVardhan sorry but its not working....

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code, you will get idea

```
ParseObject  ParseObj = new ParseObject ("YOUR_TABLE_NAME");
ParseFile file = new ParseFile("androidbegin.png", image);
ParseObj.put("profile_pic", file);
ParseObj.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
    @Override
    public void done(ParseException arg0) {
        if (arg0 == null) {
            Log.i("LOG_OUTPUT", "Data saved in sever");
        } else {
            Log.e("LOG_OUTPUT", "Data not saved in server");

        }
    }
});
file.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
    @Override
    public void done(ParseException arg0) {
        try {
            if (arg0 == null) {
                Log.e("LOG_OUTPUT", "imageFile is saved");
            } else {
                Log.e("LOG_OUTPUT", "imageFile is not saved");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

**This works for me**

```
                       imageView1.buildDrawingCache();
                        Bitmap bitmap =imageView1.getDrawingCache();
                            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                            // Compress image to lower quality scale 1 -
                            // 100
                            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,
                                    100, stream);
                            byte[] image = stream.toByteArray();

                            // Create the ParseFile
                            ParseFile file = new ParseFile(
                                    "Profile.png", image);

                            // file.getUrl();
                            // Upload the image into Parse Cloud
                            file.saveInBackground();

                            // Create a New Class called "ImageUpload"
                            // in Parse
                            final ParseObject imgupload = new ParseObject(
                                    "ImageUpload");

                            // Create a column named "ImageName" and set
                            // the string
                            imgupload.put("ImageName",
                                    "Profile Picture");

                            // Create a column named "ImageFile" and
                            // insert the image
                            imgupload.put("ImageFile", file);

                            // Create the class and the columns
                            imgupload.saveInBackground();

                            imgupload
                                    .saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void done(
                                                ParseException e) {
                                            if (e == null) {
                                                // Success!

                                                String objectId = imgupload
                                                        .getObjectId();
                                                Editor editor = sharedpref_objid
                                                        .edit();
                                                editor.putString(
                                                        "objid",
                                                        objectId);

                                                Toast.makeText(
                                                        getApplicationContext(),
                                                        objectId,
                                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                                        .show();

                                                editor.commit();

                                            } else {
                                                // Failure!
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
```